# SQL Server 2012 paging and subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a of TSQL something like this

```
declare 
    @_RowsPerPage INT = 10,
    @_PageNumber INT = 1

select  *,
        (
            select  col
            from    TAB2
            where   TAB2.num = TAB1.num
        )
from    TAB1
order by TAB1.num
OFFSET (@_PageNumber - 1) * @_RowsPerPage ROWS
FETCH NEXT @_RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY
```

it's on SQL Server 2012 and it does paging of the records.

Suppose I have 50 records in TAB1 and at a time only 10 is going to be displayed because of paging.
Now question I have is does the subquery that I have in there executes for 50 records (*which table actually has*) or for 10 records (*which query returns*)?

**UPDATE (2014-12-29)**

From answers its pretty clear that subquery is executing for 50 records here which is not what I or anyone else would want to have. So if I break down this query into 2 like below would it be better? would subquery execute for paged records only then?

```
declare
    @_RowsPerPage INT = 10,
    @_PageNumber INT = 1

declare @_tempTbl table (num int)

insert into @_tempTbl
select  num
from    TAB1
order by TAB1.num
OFFSET (@_PageNumber - 1) * @_RowsPerPage ROWS
FETCH NEXT @_RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY


select  TAB1.*,
        (
            select  col
            from    TAB2
            where   TAB2.num = TAB1.num
        )
from    @_tempTbl as TAB1
```

Comment: It depends on page number, first page will execute for 10 records, page 5 will execute for 50 records.

Comment: About your update: It is not right to do it becuse in the second query the outer apply between the @_tempTbl and  TAB2 you are still running on each record from @_tempTbl to find the match in "TAB2" . And you add to the execution more operation (insert into ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This query is not a "LEFT OUTER JOIN", it is more "OUTER APPLY" .
2. In this query, If the relation between the tables is not ONE to ONE, you will get an error message:

"`Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. "

there for you need to add to you subquery the SELECT TOP(1) ... ORDER BY  ASC/DESC.

FOR EXAMPLE :

```
USE NORTHWND
GO
declare 
@_RowsPerPage INT = 10,
@_PageNumber INT = 1

select  *,
    (
        select  TOP(1)
            TAB2.OrderID
        from    dbo.[Orders] TAB2
        where   TAB2.CustomerID = TAB1.CustomerID
        ORDER BY OrderID asc
    )
from    [dbo].[Customers]  TAB1
order by TAB1.PostalCode
OFFSET (@_PageNumber - 1) * @_RowsPerPage ROWS
FETCH NEXT @_RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY ;

go
```

2. The execution paln is "NESTED LOOP" (left outer join) . for each row from TAB1 it will access to table TAB2 .
so if you are having 100 rows in TAB1 and 50 rows in TAB2 , than you will access to TAB2 100 times .(is it gone a be scan or seek on the tables ? It depends on the index tunning on the table)

Comment: You're correct it's NESTED LOOP JOIN, so it eventually goes to join one by one. If you checked the query plan, it will pick up the 10 records from table `TAB1`, then join the data in table `TAB2`. So, it will execute 10 times. If the `@_PageNumber` is 10, then it will pull 100 records from table `TAB1` and join `TAB2` for 100 times. So, your answer is not correct as it doesn't always pull all the records from table `TAB1`. And, I don't agree with your 1st point. It's NESTED LOOP JOIN, but not OUTER APPLY.

Comment: Take this query as is and exec him . See what you will get .

Comment: @itzikPaz can you provide comments on update please.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, this is a left outer join query, so it should be written that way (though the query optimizer is likely taking care of that for you, behind the scenes).

To answer your question, this query has to scan the table first, and then return just the rows you wanted.  Therefore, if you have 50 records in TAB1 that pass the join condition to TAB2, it's going to go over 50 records before it returns the 10 you asked for.

Re-write your query as this, to be clearer:

```
declare @_RowsPerPage INT = 10,
    @_PageNumber INT = 1

select  TAB1.*, TAB2.col
from    TAB1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB2 ON TAB1.num = TAB2.num
order by TAB1.num
OFFSET (@_PageNumber - 1) * @_RowsPerPage ROWS
FETCH NEXT @_RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Isn't the original query actually equivalent to a left join? If there is no match a sub query in a select returns null.

Comment: @dodexahedron can you provide your views on updated question please